# Django diferencia entre post mediante framework y curl

Tags: python, django, api, djangorestframework

como están?
Estoy haciendo una rest API muy sencilla. Para guardar algunos registros en una base de datos sqllite y sacar algunos parámetros.
Mi idea principal es que pueda almacenar información al enviar un post con un json. La información va a venir de la siguiente forma: {"data": [1, -2, 3.2, 7]}, por cada valor de la lista, tengo que generar un nuevo registro en mi DB.
Mi código por el momento es bastante sencillo... claramente luego voy a procesar la lista y almacenar los registros correspondientes.. por ahora se ve asi:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def addRegister(request):

    print("Recibi ==> " , type(request), " ==> " , dict(request.data))

    rta = {"Response":"Guardado"}
    return Response(rta)
```

Mi gran duda surge de que cuando utilizo la opción que da django para realizar el post (ingreso al endpoint , selecciono la opción post y coloco MediaType= "application/json") y llenando el contenido con el diccionario de prueba : `{"data": [1, -2, 3.2, 7]}` todo va bien.

```
Recibi ==>  <class 'rest_framework.request.Request'>  ==>  {'data': [1, -2, 3.2, 7]}
[16/Feb/2022 14:44:57] "POST /add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5631
```

Ahora cuando quiero utilizar curl pareciera no funcionar... estoy usando el siguiente comando (que entiendo es equivalente):

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/add/ -H 'Content-Type:
application/json' -d '{"data": [1, -2, 3.2, 7]}'
```

Cuando envio este post.. retorna al cliente HTTP/1.1 200.. pero en la consola no me recibe los datos e imprime un error:

```
Recibi ==>  <class 'rest_framework.request.Request'>  ==>  {}
[16/Feb/2022 14:53:46] "POST /add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 23
[16/Feb/2022 14:53:46] code 400, message Bad request version ('7]}')
[16/Feb/2022 14:53:46] "{"data": [1, -2, 3.2, 7]}" 400 -
```

Sospecho que quizás este armando mal el curl, pero según vi en internet la data se coloca de esa forma. Que puede ser? Me falta algo en el código?
Desde ya muchas gracias a todos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo probé de esta manera y me funciono bien

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/add/ -d '{"data": [1, -2, 3.2, 7]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Te recomiendo la aplicación Postman para que puedas probar tus endpoints.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Sabia que era algo sencillo pero no me daba cuenta! Muchas gracias!